# bash line interpreting process

Tags: bash, scripting, interpreter

I would like to understand the exact process of line interpretation executed by bash.

from GNU bash reference manual:

```
When a simple command is executed, the shell performs the following expansions, assignments, and redirections, from left to right.

1. The words that the parser has marked as variable assignments (those preceding the command name) and redirections are saved for later processing.

2. The words that are not variable assignments or redirections are expanded (see Shell Expansions). If any words remain after expansion, the first word is taken to be the name of the command and the remaining words are the arguments.

3. Redirections are performed as described above (see Redirections).

4. The text after the ‘=’ in each variable assignment undergoes tilde expansion, parameter expansion, command substitution, arithmetic expansion, and quote removal before being assigned to the variable.

If no command name results, the variable assignments affect the current shell environment. Otherwise, the variables are added to the environment of the executed command and do not affect the current shell environment. If any of the assignments attempts to assign a value to a readonly variable, an error occurs, and the command exits with a non-zero status.

If no command name results, redirections are performed, but do not affect the current shell environment. A redirection error causes the command to exit with a non-zero status.

If there is a command name left after expansion, execution proceeds as described below. Otherwise, the command exits. If one of the expansions contained a command substitution, the exit status of the command is the exit status of the last command substitution performed. If there were no command substitutions, the command exits with a status of zero.
```

now let’s take a simple example:

```
var="hello friend"

echo ${var}s > log.txt
```

what happens now?

according the reference the var assignment (1) will take place after expansions (4) , but how the shell can expand the var without performing the variable assignment first?

I don't know if it's something that I missed here or just misunderstanding of the manual.

I'll appreciate if you'll be able to give me additional examples for further understanding.

thanks

Comment: These are *two* separate commands... So bash will follow the sequence of steps for *each* of them

Answer (score 2):

> ...expansions, assignments, and redirections, from left to right.

The manual does *not* mention that it also parses from **top to bottom**, one line after the other. It talks ony about **simple commands**.

You can always change

```
cmd1
cmd2
```

into

```
cmd1; cmd2
```

But normally

```
com ma nd 1
co mma nd 2
```

is preferred by humans to

```
com ma nd 1; co mma nd 2
```

---

In bash you do not have `=` vs. `==`, so it takes this special syntax for **assignments**. **Redirections** are also mentioned, and these you can put anywhere:

```
> log.txt echo ${var}s 
echo ${var}s>log.txt
```

---

**Line continuation** is the other way round:

```
com \
mand 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 simple statements, 1 per line. So for the first line steps 1,2 and 3 do nothing, then step 4 is the variable assignment.

For the second line, the variable is expanded in step 1.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the same line. The shell will follow these steps twice.

Additionally note that these:

```
var="hello friend"; echo ${var}s > log.txt
```

are also two simple commands. But this:

```
varr="hello friend" echo ${varr}s > log.txt
```

is one simple command. **In this case your doubt applies**: `${varr}` will expand to an empty string (unless it was assigned earlier; I deliberately used a new name, so the old assignment doesn't interfere).